# Gist One-Box is too large

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

When one-boxing gists, the resulting message is huge (about 30 lines). This takes up too much space in the chat. Can we make it smaller? Like say… 10 to 15 lines or something?

[image: the gist is too damn high]

Comment: We ask users to use a paste service when they try to post a large block of code in chat, so the resulting onebox being larger than the code is not ideal.

Comment: That does seem a little excessive.