# Minor encoding issue with xkcd alt texts in chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

It is a fairly well-known [albeit undocumented feature of SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting) that [xkcd](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) links one-box, and they even preserve the alt text. This is a great feature (which can't be said about one-boxing [GitHub gists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345136/gist-one-box-is-too-large)).

[Today's xkcd post](https://xkcd.com/1824/) revealed a minor encoding issue wherein an [em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash_versus_em_dash) in the alt text got mangled in the one-box:

[image]

Since I know nothing about encodings, this is all I figured out:

```
>>> unicodedata.name('—')
'EM DASH'
```

Both sites seem to have an encoding of UTF-8. I'm using Firefox 45.8 on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian).

Answer (score 32):

I suspect that the Stack Exchange Chat one-boxing uses the XKCD JSON feed.

The Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) for 'EM DASH' is [U+2014](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128), so in JSON it *should* get encoded as the `'\u2014'` escape sequence. Its UTF-8 encoding is `'\xe2\x80\x94'`, but somehow those three bytes have each been encoded as separate `'\u'` sequences, yielding `'\u00e2\u0080\u0094'`.

This is a [known issue with the XKCD JSON feed](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610094709/http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=113522), but I thought that it would have been fixed by now...

---

It appears that this is a UTF-8 / [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). FWIW, it can be reversed in Python like this:

```python
import json
a = '''"Be careful\u00e2\u0080\u0094it's breeding season"'''
print(json.loads(a).encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
```

#### Output

```
Be careful—it's breeding season
```

Comment: Thank you for leading me in the right direction! The encoding issue is still present in 2018. Here's a way around it in JavaScript: `decodeURIComponent(escape(a))`

Comment: The link to forums.xkcd.com was broken, apparently that forum does exist anymore.  I have taken the liberty to replace it with a link to an archived version.